# Updating view without reload in laravel mvc

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.4, bootstrap-select

I am using Laravel 5.4 in my project and I'm making a simple dashboard with some charts that desplay informations from mySql database.

I put some dropdown lists as filters so that the user can filter the dashboard as he like to. I put the dropdown lists in a form and i filled them from my controller without ajax, simply using get method and bootstrap-select.

This is my code how looks like:

```
       <form id="filter"  method="GET">

                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <select class="selectpicker "  name="siteF" id="siteF" data-width="100px" data-actions-box="true" data-style="btn-warning" title="Site">
                        <option>All</option>
                        @foreach($SiteFilter as $site)
                        <option>{{ $site->site_name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>

                <select class="selectpicker "  name="yearF" id="yearF" data-size="5" data-width="100px" data-actions-box="true" data-style="btn-warning" title="Year">
                    <option>All</option>
                    @foreach($YearFilter as $year)
                        <option>{{ $year->year }}</option>
                    @endforeach

                </select>

                <select class="selectpicker "  name="operatorF" id="operatorF" data-size="5" data-width="100px" data-actions-box="true" data-style="btn-warning" title="Operator">
                    <option>All</option>
                    @foreach($OperatorFilter as $operator)
                        <option>{{ $operator->operator }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

                <select class="selectpicker "  name="parkingF" id="parkingF" data-width="100px" data-actions-box="true" data-style="btn-warning" title="Parking">
                    <option>All</option>
                    @foreach($ParkingFilter as $parking)
                        <option>{{ $parking->parking }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>



                <button type="submit"  class="btn bg-deep-orange waves-effect">
                    <i class="material-icons">search</i>

                </button>
            </form>
```

This is the part in the controller where i fill the lists:

```
    //----------------------------------- 1/ filter of sites-----------------------------------

    $SiteFilter=  DB::table('transactions')
        ->select('site_name')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

    //-----------------------------------end of filter of sites-----------------------------------

    //----------------------------------- 2/ filter of years-----------------------------------

    $YearFilter=  DB::table('transactions')
        ->select(DB::raw("YEAR(transaction_created_at) as year"))
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

    //-----------------------------------end of filter of years-----------------------------------

    //----------------------------------- 3/ filter of operators-----------------------------------

    $OperatorFilter=  DB::table('transactions')
        ->select('operator_id as operator')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

    //-----------------------------------end of filter of operators-----------------------------------

    //----------------------------------- 4/ filter of parkings-----------------------------------

    $ParkingFilter=  DB::table('transactions')
        ->select('parking')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

    //-----------------------------------end of filter of parkings-----------------------------------
```

and this is an example of a chart:

```
      //-----------------------------------Donutchart: number of transactions per operator-----------------------------------
    $donutData=  DB::table('transactions')
        ->select('operator_id as operator',DB::raw('count(id) as num'))
        ->where(function ($query) {

            if((Input::get('operatorF') != "")&&(Input::get('operatorF') != "All"))
                $query->where('operator_id','=',Input::get('operatorF') );

            if((Input::get('parkingF') != "")&&(Input::get('parkingF') != "All"))
                $query->where('parking','=',Input::get('parkingF') );

            if((Input::get('yearF') != "")&&(Input::get('yearF') != "All"))
                $query->where('transaction_created_at', '>=',(string)Input::get('yearF'));

            if((Input::get('siteF') != "")&&(Input::get('siteF') != "All"))
                $query->where('site_name','=',Input::get('siteF') );

        })
        ->groupby('operator')
        ->orderby('operator')
        ->get();

    $donut_data='[';
    foreach($donutData as $rec)
    {
        $donut_data=$donut_data.'{"label":'.$rec->operator.',"value":'.$rec->num.'},';

    }
    $x=strlen($donut_data);
    $donut_data[$x-1]=']';
    //-----------------------------------end of Donutchart: number of transactions per operator-----------------------------------
```

The response returned with this code is sent to javascript to make the donut chart.

So my quetion is what should i do to use the filters without refreshing my dashboard page in fact in the currant state when the page is reloaded i loose the dropdown filters last choice so i the user can't tell which filter and value he used. And i didn't know how to implement the ajax in my project. Any help?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: ok, learn ajax and use `Session` if you don't want to lose filter values after page refresh. `Session::put()`, `Session::remove()` and `Session::get()` can be your methods to use. Put `use Session;` before class declaration in your Laravel Controller file.

Comment: okey thank you i'll do that